# Galois group of a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

To find the Galois group of the polynomial $X^3-X-t\in\mathbb{C}[t]$, an approach is to compute the discriminant (equal $(2-\sqrt{27}t)(2+\sqrt{27}t)$) which is not a square in $\mathbb{C}[t]$ so the Galois group is not a subgroup of $A_3$ and must be $S_3$.

> Is there a way without using the discriminant? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the extension $A=\mathbb{C}[t,x]/(x^3-x-t)$ obtained by adjoining a root of $X^3-X-t$, and let $K$ denote the field of fractions of $A$.  Since $t=x^3-x$ in $A$, $A$ is just a polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$.  Any root of $X^3-X-t$ in $K$ would be integral over $\mathbb{C}[t]$, and hence in $A$ since it is integrally closed.  If a polynomial $p(x)$ is a root of $X^3-X-t$, then it satisfies $p(x)^3-p(x)=x^3-x$.  Comparing degrees, we see $p(x)=ax+b$ must be linear, and so we get $$a^3x^3+3a^2bx^2+(3ab^2-a)x+(b^3-b)=x^3-x.$$
It is easy to deduce from this equation that $a=1$ and $b=0$, so $p(x)=x$.

Thus $x$ is the only root of $X^3-X-t$ in $K$.  Since $X^3-X-t$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}(t)$, $K$ has degree $3$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$.  Thus the splitting field of $X^3-X-t$ has degree greater than $3$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$, and it follows that the Galois group must be all of $S_3$.